# how to connect Jenkins installed on Ubunt2 wsl to internet

Tags: jenkins

i have installed Jenkins on ubunt2 wsl.However i am unable to download any plugin as my jenkins installed is unale to connect to internet.Can anyone please guilde me on this?

Answer (score 0):

We need to do Network reset

Open Command Prompt as an Administrator and type these commands:

netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns